# Do we need transit visa if we stay for 12 hours in international Haneda airport?

Tags: transit, transit-visas, japan

I have a 12 hours transit at Tokyo International Haneda (HND), Tokyo airport on my way. I don't have to change airports. Do I have to apply for a transit visa? Is there a minimum hours that we can stay in the airport?

Answer (score 2):

If this is single ticket you typically don't need a Visa and the airport is open 24 hours (unless Covid makes a mess again).

However there are always exceptions so I recommend to put your exact details into this form: https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/passport-visa-health-travel-document-requirements.htm

If this a self connection, things are much more complicated and we would need a lot more details to assess this.